# Make a clear(transluscent) UIBarButttonItem IOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to set the tint color for a UIBarButtonItem using the following code, but all I get is a black button. Is there a way to accomplish this without the need to use custom images?

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] SetTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]]:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a custom UIBarButtonItem with a button

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//set the frame of the button to the size of the image (see note below)
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
button.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];    
//create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Comment: I could do this, the main problem is that I have designers adding buttons via a storyboard. Doing it this way would mean I would have to add all buttons programmatically.

Comment: you can create outlets to your customBarItem and then can set the property of customBarItem like this     customBarItem.customView=button;

Answer (score 0):

If your UIToobar or UINavigationBar is translucent, bar buttons automatically become translucent.

`[[self.navigationController navigationBar] setTranslucent:YES];`

AFAIK, You can't make a bar button alone translucent.

Comment: I did this and it seems that the UIBarButtonItems are still coming through as black. Any ideas?